# Left align labels - iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel

Both labels are left aligned and with each leading equal to one another, in fact the frame itself is correct, but the text of the bigger label doesn't start right at the beginning of its frame so the 2 labels are not aligned.

[image]

Any idea on how to align them properly?

Comment: By adding a negative `margin-left` to the associated element. Without you posting your code, we can't possibly fix the bug in it.

Comment: No code required, I made a simple test project to show it: http://www.filedropper.com/testlabelalignment otherwise just add 2 labels to an empty controller set their fontSize really different from one another (20-70), align leading and trailing and look.

Comment: Your link requires creation of an account, and no-one is going to create an account just to download your code. You don't even specify which **language** you're using to create your app. C? C++? C#? Swift? Ruby? LUA? Where's your **CSS**? Either way, you simply either need to set a negative `margin-left`, or remove a margin / padding: `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`.

Comment: @Obsidian Age. The question has UILabel as a tag, therefore it is not html/css related and thus your answers aren't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the padding from the label. You don't state the language, so here it is in Swift, this removes all padding, you can of course just remove the left padding.

```
@IBDesignable
class NoPaddingLabel: UILabel {
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

In the storyboard change the type of the label from UILabel to NoPaddingLabel